# rpm installation error

Tags: installation, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install an RPM compat-db-4.1.25-9 on oracle linux enterprise, since it's required to install WebCenter...however the rpm installation is throwing a warning and then not working

```
[root@devsebl downloads]# rpm -i compat-db-4.1.25-9.rpm 
warning: compat-db-4.1.25-9.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 9b3c94f4
[root@devsebl downloads]# rpm -q compat-db-4.1.25-9.rpm 
package compat-db-4.1.25-9.rpm is not installed
```

Any idea what that warning means and why its crashing there?

I tried to use Yum, but its not available i guess:

```
[root@devsebl downloads]# yum search compat-db
Loaded plugins: security
Warning: No matches found for: compat-db
No Matches found
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a question for ServerFault and not for StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a warning. The package *has* in fact been installed.

The second is because every query option other than `-p` takes the package *name*, not the package filename.

The third is because the package doesn't exist in any yum repository your system knows about. This may not be a problem though. See point 1.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add additional sources for yum to find this particular package (assuming you are using the correct package name).